# Do bundle-size get affected by how you pass props?

Tags: reactjs

I try to understand how bundle-size gets affected by how you pass the props to components and if its relevant.

Let's assume we're passing declared props then we can do one of two ways:

```
// 1
<Component 
    culture={culture}
    disabled={disabled}
    user={user}
/>

// 2
<Component 
  {...{
      culture,
      disabled,
      user
   }}
/>
```

A project with number two should in theory result in a smaller bundle because of lesser chars.
Am I thinking right? and is it relevant?

Comment: Irrelevant because of property/variable mangling by minifiers like terser.

Comment: Ahh thats true, good point thank you.